# Clean way in Python to open Windows default web browser with a URL and then close it after a few seconds

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, subprocess, python-webbrowser, taskkill

As the title suggests I want to find a way in Python to do that.
I have tried:

**1) Selenium + Webdriver** : I don't like the dependencies, like a user need to install a webdriver, tried bypassing it with webdriver-manager module but still there was some issues cause I don't know for sure that a user might have Chrome installed, or Firefox etc...so I don't know what webdriver to choose. Also speed was not great in this case.

**2) webbrowser module**: Very fast way to open the default browser at a specific URL. Can't control if it opens in a new window or in a new tab (I know there is a open_new method but couldn't get it to work). **Main problem is I can't close the tab/window**.

**3) subprocesses module**:
`p = subprocess.Popen(f'{path_to_browser} https://www.reddit.com/')`
I have found a way to list browsers installed in a system using the pybrowsers module so `path_to_variable` is determined at runtime. I can't seem to kill the process though...

I have tried `p.kill()` or `os.system("taskkill /F /pid "+str(p.pid))` or
`os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGILL)` but nothing works cause I believe p.pid is not the process that I need to kill (it has spawned a bunch of other processes)

Is there a clean way to do this kind of thing? I could always do `os.system("taskkill /im {browser.exe} /f")` but this will terminate all open tabs...